Melting Ice Caps: How Does It Impact Earth's Rotation and the Length of a Day?
Melting Polar Ice Caps and Earth's Rotation.
The polar ice caps contain an estimated mass of $ m = 3 \cdot 10^{19} \, kg $. This mass contributes almost nothing to the Earth's moment of inertia since it is located very close to the Earth's rotational axis.
Problem Statement.
(a) How does the Earth's angular velocity change if the polar ice caps melt and the resulting water is evenly distributed across the Earth's surface?
(b) How does this change affect the length of a day?
Attempt.
The moment of inertia of the Earth before and after the redistribution of the ice is given by:
\begin{align*}
I_i &= \frac{2}{5} M r^2 \\
I_f &= \frac{2}{5} (M - m) r^2 + \frac{2}{3} m r^2
\end{align*}
Applying the law of conservation of angular momentum, we have:
\begin{align*}
I_i \omega_i &= I_f \omega_f \\
\omega_f &= \frac{I_i}{I_f} \omega_i \\
\omega_f &\approx 7.27 \cdot 10^{-5} \, s^{-1}
\end{align*}
The change in the length of a day is determined by:
$
\Delta T = \frac{2 \pi}{\omega_f} - \frac{2 \pi}{\omega_i}
$
With the given values, this results in an increase in the length of a day by approximately:
$
\Delta T \approx 0.288 \, s.
$
Questions.
I know there is already a post online about this topic, but I felt it was missing a conceptual approach to solving the problem, so here is my take. I also noticed that the old post suggested using the conservation of rotational kinetic energy to solve the problem. I was wondering if that is indeed the correct approach, or whether it would also be valid to use the conservation of angular momentum, given that no external forces act on the Earth.
For my solution, I modeled all the water from the melted ice as being distributed in a shell at exactly $ r $, the radius of the Earth. I made this assumption because the rise in water level would be approximately $ 58.8 \, m $, which is negligible compared to the Earth's radius.
I would greatly appreciate any responses or insights into whether this conceptual framework and the choice of conservation laws are valid. Do you think this is a reasonable approach, or would you suggest any changes to make it more accurate? Thank you very much!

Conservation of angular momentum is correct, since only $I\omega$ is constant.
Of course, $I\omega^2$ changes, so something is doing work in transporting the water away from the poles. You should figure out what that is.

The ice cap at the north pole is floating. It does not affect the rotation of the earth at all when it melts.
Let us divide the ocean into 2 parts - water and ice. Without the water, the ice would fall to the ocean floor. Water exerts an upward force on the ice that exactly balances the weight.
Consider just the water. It has an ice shaped hole in it. Ice is less dense than water, some some of the ice sticks up above the water. Suppose you removed the ice and filled the hole with water. You might say the hole still exists, but it is harder to tell where the boundary is. The ocean still pushes up on whatever is filling the hole just as hard. The ocean stays still if water fills the hole up to the surface. That means the downward force of the water is just as strong as the upward force. The weight of the water that fills the hole is the same as the weight of the ice that made the hole.
When the ice melts, it gets denser. The new volume is exactly enough to fill the hole. No water is redistributed anywhere.
Ice melting in Greenland is a different story. Likewise Antarctica. For that ice, your calculations are correct. Fortunately most of the ice is in AntArtictica. The floating ice is melting. Some of the continental ice is melting. But the largest part does not appear to be melting. So the difference in rotational speed will be smaller than you predict.

ofc you're correct, but I don't think that is what the question "wanted". I should know better, I am currently producing a record of arctic snow depth and boreal see ice for winter 23-24 at work.

Your assumptions are correct but you have to think also tidal forces act on earth by moon and sun. Since earth sea level increasing this will also changes the earth's rotational axes.
